# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined chai.js

Tags: reactjs, chai-enzyme

I have a problem testing my react app
the bug says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
This is the code:

```
beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = mount(<LoggedInLayout/>);
    });

    it('allows to set props', () => {
        const username = 'testUser';
        wrapper.setProps({username: username});
        expect(wrapper.props().username).to.equal(username);
    });

    it('renders all subcomponents', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('ul.ant-menu')).to.have.lengthOf(2);
        expect(wrapper.find('.ant-menu-item')).to.have.lengthOf(3);
        expect(wrapper.find('button')).to.have.lengthOf(2);
        expect(wrapper.find('.ant-input')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
        expect(wrapper.find('.anticon')).to.have.lengthOf(2);
    });
```

Comment: Can you try using `beforeEach(()=>{ wrapper = mount(<LoggedInLayout/>); });` instead

Comment: its mocha globals and should be beforeEach